# Не удается залогиниться

Tags: веб-программирование, php, авторизация, mysql

Есть файл с кодом регистрации по внесению вводимых данных в базу данных:

```
<?php
  // include function files for this application
  require_once('bookmark_fns.php');

  //create short variable names
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $username=$_POST['username'];
  $passwd=$_POST['passwd'];
  $passwd2=$_POST['passwd2'];
  // start session which may be needed later
  // start it now because it must go before headers
  session_start();
  try
  {
    // check forms filled in
    if (!filled_out($_POST))
    {
      throw new Exception('You have not filled the form out correctly - please go back'
          .' and try again.');    
    }

    // email address not valid
    if (!valid_email($email))
    {
      throw new Exception('That is not a valid email address.  Please go back '
                          .' and try again.');
    }

    // passwords not the same 
    if ($passwd != $passwd2)
    {
      throw new Exception('The passwords you entered do not match - please go back'
                           .' and try again.');
    }

    // check password length is ok
    // ok if username truncates, but passwords will get
    // munged if they are too long.
    if (strlen($passwd)<6 || strlen($passwd) >16)
    {
      throw new Exception('Your password must be between 6 and 16 characters.'
                           .'Please go back and try again.');
    }

    // attempt to register
    // this function can also throw an exception
    register($username, $email, $passwd);
    // register session variable 
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;

    // provide link to members page
    do_html_header('Registration successful');
    echo 'Your registration was successful.  Go to the members page '
          .'to start setting up your bookmarks!';
    do_html_url('member.php', 'Go to members page');

   // end page
   do_html_footer();
  }
  catch (Exception $e)
  {
     do_html_header('Problem:');
     echo $e->getMessage(); 
     do_html_footer();
     exit;
  } 
?>
```

**Функция register вносит данные в базу данных:**

```
function register($username, $email, $password)
// register new person with db
// return true or error message
{
  // connect to db
  $conn = db_connect();

  // check if username is unique 
  $result = $conn->query("select * from user where username='$username'"); 
  if (!$result)
    throw new Exception('Could not execute query');
  if ($result->num_rows>0) 
    throw new Exception('That username is taken - go back and choose another one.');

  // if ok, put in db
  $result = $conn->query("insert into user values 
                         ('$username', sha1('$password'), '$email')");
  if (!$result)
    throw new Exception('Could not register you in database - please try again later.');

  return true;
}
```

Есть же код по входу на сайт:

```
<?php
session_start();
// include function files for this application
require_once('bookmark_fns.php'); 
//session_start();

//create short variable names
$username = $_POST['username'];
$passwd = $_POST['passwd'];

if ($username && $passwd)
// they have just tried logging in
{
  try
  {
    login($username, $passwd);
    // if they are in the database register the user id
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
    // unsuccessful login
    do_html_header('Problem:');
    echo 'You could not be logged in. 
          You must be logged in to view this page.';
           echo $e->getMessage();
    do_html_url('login.php', 'Login');
    do_html_footer();
    exit;
  }      
}

do_html_header('Home');
check_valid_user();
// get the bookmarks this user has saved
if ($url_array = get_user_urls($_SESSION['valid_user']))
  display_user_urls($url_array);

// give menu of options
display_user_menu();

do_html_footer();
?>
```

**Функция login проверяет есть ли введенный пользовтелем с паролем в базе данных:**

```
function login($username, $password)
// check username and password with db
// if yes, return true
// else throw exception
{
  // connect to db
  $conn = db_connect();

  // check if username is unique
  $result = $conn->query("select * from user 
                         where username='$username'
                         and passwd = sha1('$password')");
  if (!$result)
     throw new Exception('Could not log you in.');

  if ($result->num_rows>0)
     return true;
  else 
     throw new Exception('Could not log you in..User does not exist.');
}
```

В результате попытки входа с существующим пользователем и паролем происходит работа ветви:

```
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
    // unsuccessful login
    do_html_header('Problem:');
    echo 'You could not be logged in. 
          You must be logged in to view this page.';
           echo $e->getMessage();
    do_html_url('login.php', 'Login');
    do_html_footer();
    exit;
  }
```

В результате выдает сообщение

You could not be logged in. You must be logged in to view this page.Could not log you in.User does not exist. 
несмотря на то что пользователи существуют

[image]

Comment: мне плохо. Кода маленько многовато.

Comment: Для решения задачи нехватает кода, выложите оставшуюся часть сюда, может мы что то и решим.. и главное полный дамп бд не забудьте прикрепить!

Answer (score 1):

Без дампа бд как я уже написал сказать что либо сложно, но я таки прочел код и могу вот что сказать, функция логин выбивает эксцепшн, почему? можно будет сказать расставив там брэйкпоинты. допустим модифицировав ее так.

```
function login($username, $password)
{
  // connect to db
   $my_return='try connect<br>';    
   $conn = db_connect();
   $my_return='Connected<br>';//перед строкой добавте проверку верности соединения.
 // check if username is unique
  $result = $conn->query("select * from user 
                     where username='$username'
                     and passwd = sha1('$password')");
  if (!$result)
    {
     $my_return.='query error<br>';
     $my_return.="select * from user 
                     where username='$username'
                     and passwd = sha1('$password')";
     return $my_return; 
     throw new Exception('Could not log you in.');
    };

  if ($result->num_rows>0){
     $my_return.='User found, all ok<br>';
     return $my_return;
  }
  else 
  {
     $my_return.='user not found in database<br>';
     $my_return.='Conected<br>';
     return $my_return;    
     throw new Exception('Could not log you in..User does not exist.');
  }
}
```

и ваш код:

```
try
{
  login($username, $passwd);
  // if they are in the database register the user id
  $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;
}
```

Заменить на:

```
//try
if(1==1)
{
  echo login($username, $passwd);
  // if they are in the database register the user id
  //$_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;
}else
```

После вышеуказаных действий на страничке вы увидите в чем именно была ошибка. если сами не поймете, в коментарий вставляйте что именно вывел скрипт.

Comment: 1=1 это что такое?

Comment: это равносильно if(true), условие у которого никогда не выполнится часть else.

или вы о моей опечатке?)) поправил, не сразу понял...

Comment: @ToRcH565 простите мне мою безграмотность, а что такое дамп бд (не минусуйте, а лучше разъясните).

Comment: содержимое базы.
с вики:

    Дамп базы данных — файл с содержимым базы данных, позволяющий воссоздать базу данных «с нуля»; создается при помощи дампера.

и поповоду дампа - это ирония, вы выложили дофига ненужного кода. для решения задачи нужны были только те куски которые я модифицировал, или файлы содержащие их.